# Linux PPPD connection terminated -> LCP terminated by peer (User request)

Tags: wireless-networking, modem, 3g, ppp, gprs

I'm trying to establish a GPRS PPP connection (to Rogers Wireless data network in Canada) using the Telit HE910 modem, but it appears that something is going wrong during DNS negotiation:

```
Serial connection established.
using channel 16
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyACM3
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0x218a9f69> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x10535642>]
sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x10535642>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0x218a9f69>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0x218a9f69>]
sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0x10535642]
sent [PAP AuthReq id=0x1 user="cm-debian" password=""]
rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0x218a9f69]
rcvd [PAP AuthAck id=0x1 ""]
PAP authentication succeeded
kernel does not support PPP filtering
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x2 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [LCP TermReq id=0x3 "User request"]
LCP terminated by peer (User request)
sent [LCP TermAck id=0x3]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x3 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14>]
Discarded non-LCP packet when LCP not open
Connection terminated.
Modem hangup
```

Here are the PPP options in effect:

```
pppd options in effect:
debug                   # (from /etc/ppp/pppd_script)
nodetach                # (from /etc/ppp/pppd_script)
dump                    # (from /etc/ppp/pppd_script)
noauth                  # (from /etc/ppp/pppd_script)
/dev/ttyACM3            # (from /etc/ppp/pppd_script)
115200                  # (from /etc/ppp/pppd_script)
lock                    # (from /etc/ppp/pppd_script)
connect /usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/hsdpa_connect    # (from /etc/ppp/pppd_script)
crtscts                 # (from /etc/ppp/pppd_script)
modem                   # (from /etc/ppp/options)
noaccomp                # (from /etc/ppp/pppd_script)
asyncmap 0              # (from /etc/ppp/options)
nopcomp                 # (from /etc/ppp/pppd_script)
lcp-echo-failure 5      # (from /etc/ppp/pppd_script)
lcp-echo-interval 5     # (from /etc/ppp/pppd_script)
lcp-max-terminate 10    # (from /etc/ppp/options)
lcp-max-configure 10    # (from /etc/ppp/options)
lcp-max-failure 10      # (from /etc/ppp/options)
show-password           # (from /etc/ppp/pppd_script)
novj                    # (from /etc/ppp/pppd_script)
novjccomp               # (from /etc/ppp/pppd_script)
ipcp-accept-local       # (from /etc/ppp/pppd_script)
ipcp-accept-remote      # (from /etc/ppp/pppd_script)
defaultroute            # (from /etc/ppp/pppd_script)
usepeerdns              # (from /etc/ppp/pppd_script)
nobsdcomp               # (from /etc/ppp/pppd_script)
noipx                   # (from /etc/ppp/options)
```

And here is my chatfile:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Connection to the network
'' AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.com"
# Dial the number.
OK ATD*99***1#
# The modem is waiting for the following answer
CONNECT ''
```

Can anyone help me to understand why the peer would send me a LCP TermReq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that runs into this, the issue ended up being that my mobile data provider (who piggybacks on the rogers network, but is not actually rogers) had their own private APN and I needed to update my chat script to use the private provider APN name instead of rogers' public one.